# Apache POI excel cell character Limit

Tags: excel, limit, apache-poi, cell, dataformat

First of all I'm new to POI. I am extracting data from backend and saving it to an excel file. But I noticed that one cell only allows a max of 10 characters. This does not happen on other cells. Can I change the limit of the characters on a cell. Will dataFormat do it? Does dataFormat only work on integers? How about strings?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is some formatting defined in your original Excel file. `POI` doesn't enforce the limit of `10` characters.  This you can verify be manually writing large text into the cell in question. If so, please update the cell format style of the excel and try.

You may want to use

```
  HSSFCell.setCellStyle
  HSSFCell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
```

to change the cell's type/style through the code.